# Android: Calling finish() on activity after rotating restarts activity

Tags: java, android

I have an Android studio project consisting of 3 activities, A1, A2 and A3.

A1 is starting A2 and A2 can start A3 or go back to A1. In A3 you can either return to A2 or return some updated information back to A1, by pressing two different buttons.

My idea to return data from A3 to A1 was to pass it through A2 and then calling finish() on A2 inside its onActivityResult method. While I don't know that's the best way to do it, it seems to work.

Now if I don't rotate the device there is no problems whatsoever, information gets returned to A1 from A3. If I rotate it once and then press either button  it restarts the activity A3 and I cannot figure out why. Rotating it once and then back again also work as intended.

Here are some code snippets.

**Starting A3 from A2**

```
    infoIntent.setClass(this, A3.class);
    if(infoSet)
    {
        infoIntent.putExtra("tvName", name);
        infoIntent.putExtra("tvMemory", memory);
        infoIntent.putExtra("tvLaptop", laptop);
    }
    startActivityForResult(infoIntent, REQUEST_CODE_EDIT);
```

**Setting button listeners in A3**

```
        btnOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            returnAndUpdateInfo(view);
        }
    });

    btnCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, infoIntent);
            finish();
        }
    });
```

I can't for the life of me figure out why A3 doesn't finish only when the screen has been rotated once.

The onActivityResult in A2 doesn't even get called.

Comment: Use Fragments and simplify your life.

Comment: Yeah you're right, this was an exercise that asked us to use activities though.

Answer (score 0):

When you are rotating  your device . whole activity is being recreated. so i would suggest you to use different  approach.

use one global class and in that use global variable . When you want to pass data, just assign that data to new global variable. Let me show you.

```
Public static String data = "";

from your Activity A1 
Global.data = "your data";
```

when you want to use that data use

```
Global.data
```

i hope i'm getting your point

Comment: While I understand your solution to the passing of data, it's not really the problem I'm trying to solve.

It's the fact that rotating the device once, causes it to restart when I call finish() on it. Not rotating it or rotating it back to its original orientation does not cause this.